# Animating div box from top using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want to animate div box and button from top after clicking the button and return the box and button to initial position on clicking the same button.

css:

```
#box{
    position:relative;
    width:500px;height:200px;
    margin-top:200px;
    border:2px solid black;
    }

#box .info-box{
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;height:200px;
    top:-200px;
    background:green;

#box .button{
    position:absolute;
    width:30px;height:30px;
    background:red;
    top:30px;right:10px;
    }
```

Html:

```
    <div id="box">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="info-box"></div>
    </div>
```

jQuery to animate the box on initial click.

```
    $(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({top:-30});
    $(".info-box").animate({top:0}, 300)
    });
```

I want to animate `info-box` to fill the box and `button` to animate outside the box (top:-30px) after cliking the button and want to return the info-box and button at initial position after clicking the same button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
var isAnimate = false;
$(".button").click(function(){
    if(isAnimate){
       $(this).animate({top:30});    
      $(".info-box").animate({top:-200}, 300)
      isAnimate = false;
    }else{
      $(this).animate({top:-30});    
      $(".info-box").animate({top:0}, 300)
       isAnimate = true;
    }        
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6kzUV/

I hope it helps.